# Sort Frequency of observations as decreasing in R

Tags: r

I have created a table in **R** with:

```
as.data.frame(table(mydata$Place))
```

which now looks like:

```
2                          Var1  Freq
1                        Aapua     4
2                      Abbekås    35
3                     Abbetorp     3
4                 Abborrberget     1
5                  Abborrtjärn     2
6                   Abborrtorp     1
7                  Abborrträsk     4
```

I want to sort this list according to decreasing frequency with the highest value on top.

Comment: `df <- as.data.frame(table(mydata$Place)) ; df[order(df$Freq, decreasing=T), ]`

Comment: Or `library(dplyr);arrange(df1, desc(Freq),Var1)`